# cordova platform add error

Tags: android, node.js, cordova

I installed cordova but while adding platform it get's this error

```
Error: Failed to fetch platform cordova-android@~6.2.2
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
'C:\Windows\system32\npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file
```

But when I run `npm -v` it returns NPM version so what's the problem? I added everything in Environment variables.

Comment: `C:\Windows\system32\npm` ? which folder are you running the command? Are you running in Admin cmd?

Comment: in E: drive in project folder and yes its in admin cmd.

Comment: try moving your project to home folder and try with non admin cmd

Comment: its giving the same error .

Comment: which command did you use? and what does `which npm` give?

Comment: cordova platform add android  AND when i run npm it gives its commands list

Answer (score 0):

i just resolve the problem just type this command after installing android sdk 
`cordova platform add android --nofetch`